# How to get buttons with specifications from an array list

Tags: c#

I have this array:

```
Button[] RightArr = new Button[12] { button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, };
```

I want to check if there are 4 green backcolor buttons and if there are do something, for example: `MessageBox.Show("There are 4 green buttons");`

How can I do that?

Comment: Loop through the array, check each button's property and count how many are green, once you've exited the loop if your counter variable is 4 then outside the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do this. I have assumed, green buttons are = buttons whose backcolor is green. Feel free to change that.

```
var greenbtns = (from m in RightArr where m.BackColor == Color.Green select m).ToList();
if (greenbtns.Count >= 4) {
    MessageBox.Show("There are 4 green buttons");
}
```